# Compare each element of a columns vs all elements of a second column in in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe in pandas:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([{'A':'horses','B':'car crash'},
                       {'A':'red cars in street','B':'One horse'},
                       {'A':'Lionel Messi','B':'an octopus in a bag'},
                       {'A':'white octopus in red box','B':'messi'},
                       {'A':'Estudiantes de La Plata','B':''}])
```

I need to compare each of column `A` values with each of column `B` values, with `difflib` function.
So I need to check `horses` against `car crash`, `One horse`, etc. and get the name with higher value in `difflib` comparison.

I don't know where to start...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
from difflib import get_close_matches

df = pd.DataFrame([{'A':'horses','B':'car crash'},
                       {'A':'red cars in street','B':'One horse'},
                       {'A':'Lionel Messi','B':'an octopus in a bag'},
                       {'A':'white octopus in red box','B':'messi'},
                       {'A':'Estudiantes de La Plata','B':''}])

s = pd.Series([get_close_matches(word, df["B"], n=1, cutoff=0.0)[0] for word in df["A"]])
print(pd.DataFrame({"A": df["A"], "closest_match": s}))
```

returns:

```
                          A        closest_match
0                    horses            One horse
1        red cars in street            car crash
2              Lionel Messi                messi
3  white octopus in red box  an octopus in a bag
4   Estudiantes de La Plata  an octopus in a bag
```

Comment: Thank you! Works great! One additional question: why it is not possible to increase the cutoff value? Tried 0.5 and it gives me "IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: @Mato because cutoff allows only phrases that match above lets say 0.5. So if no phrase matches for at least 0.5, you get an empty array, so taking the first element will cause the error. Thats why I used 0.0 cut off, because you wanted the best word, if you wanted the best word above 0.5 then the code would need to be changed a little bit, but sometimes you wouldnt find a fit, so you would need to leave an empty position in the dataframe